# Setting up Sencha Touch from scratch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am new to stackoverflow and I wanted to ask about setting up the Sencha Touch on a Mac. I followed this tutorial http://davidtucker.net/blog/view/getting_setup_for_sencha_touch_2_development_on_your_mac but I think something is missing. I've done my research but I couldn't find a decent tutorial about how you are setting up the framework from the very beginning. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: go through the documents of Sencha. You will get it. And please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sencha changed a lot in the last months.

From the Sencha-Forum:

> Sencha Touch SDK Tools are not compatible to the Sencha Touch SDK in Version 2.1
>   Sencha CMD is working fine. See: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196001-quot-Not-a-recognized-Sencha-SDK-or-application-folder-quot-on-OSX-w-2.0.0-Beta-2-2.0.1-rc/page4